# Making four random numbers that add to a max value

Tags: javascript, html, function

At first I want to say that this question might have similar ones here, but my problem is something very different.

I am making four random numbers, but when one number is lower than `max/10` or higher than `max/1.2` I want to load the function again until I got the right random numbers. I wrote that like this in my script:

```
if (first < max / 10 || second < max / 10 || third < max / 10 || fourth < max / 10) { reken(max); }
if (first > max / 1.2 || second > max / 1.2 || third > max / 1.2 || fourth > max / 1.2) { reken(max); }
```

But it isn't working for me. I get numbers below 10 and sometimes up to 85. When put something stupid after the if statement like : `if(){ asdhbjka }` then the code crashes and waits for another second to run the script. In that way I get the good numbers. So I know my `if` statement is working only there is something wrong with `reken(max);`

Soo.. Hopefully you can help me.

```js
function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function reken(max) {
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
 var max = 100
    var first = random(1, max / 2.0 - 3);
    var second = random(1, max / 1.5 - 2 - first);
    var third = random(1, max / 1.2 - 1 - first - second);
    var fourth = max - first - second - third;
    if (first < max / 10 || second < max / 10 || third < max / 10 || fourth < max / 10) {
  reken(max);
    }
    if (first > max / 1.2 || second > max / 1.2 || third > max / 1.2 || fourth > max / 1.2) {
        reken(max);
    }
    
    status.innerHTML = first + " - " + second + " - " + third + " - " + fourth + " / " + (first + second + third + fourth );
}
var animateInterval = setInterval(reken,1000);
```

```html
<p id="status"></p>
```

Comment: if ((first < max / 10 || second < max / 10 || third < max / 10 || fourth < max / 10) && (first > max / 1.2 || second > max / 1.2 || third > max / 1.2 || fourth > max / 1.2)) {
        reken(max);
    }  use this..

Comment: why do I get a vote down?

Comment: I dont understand why this question has a downvote.

Comment: yes why a vote down??

Comment: Your right DevLakshman but that will not solve my problem I think

Comment: execute & tell the result please

Comment: If you are setting min and max limits then it's not random is it. Do your random generation first then offset it so it fits in your required bounds.

Comment: I think you should use a loop instead of recursion, until you find the value that satisfies your conditions.  But for your recursive version - your if statement should be a in if, else if, else ... otherwise the innerHTML is getting set when it shouldn't be.

Comment: didn't worked DevLaksham

Comment: can you give that as an answer dave? like more discriped

Comment: Voting is anonymous. Please avoid discussing them in the comments. They're not here for this purpose.

Comment: You are setting the innerHTML even when you dont want too. Only thats the problem.

Comment: You can get rid of all but the fourth condition in your first `if`, if you change `random(1,...)` to `random(max/10,...)`. Similarly, since all the upper bounds of your `random` calls are less than `max/1.2`, you can get rid of all but the fourth condition of your second `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be found in your recursive calls..

Let's make it a bit simpler:

```
function findNumber()
{
   var number = random(0,10);
   if (number < 5)
       findNumber();

   document.GetElementById("labelForMyNumber").innerText(number);
}
```

Let's run that code.. What will happen:

> Step 1: number = 6
>
> Step 2: if fails (number > 5)
>
> Step 3: label get text: `6`

Ok, let's try that again now:

> Step 1: number = 4
>
> Step 2: If succeeds (number < 5)
>
> Step 3: we call the function again
>
> Step 4: new number, this time 8
>
> Step 5: If fails (8 > 5)
>
> Step 6: We change the text to 8.
>
> BUT!! Step 7: We return to the first function! Number is now 4 again (see step 1)
>
> Step 8: We change the text to number which is 4.

You see? When you go recursive, you always return to the function before, and continue to execute that code.

Now, how to solve this?

Simple way is this:

```
function findNumber()
{
   var number = random(0,10);
   if (number < 5)
       findNumber();
   else
       document.GetElementById("labelForMyNumber").innerText(number);
}
```

---

Your code by this logic should be:

```
function reken(max) {
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    var max = 100
    var first = random(1, max / 2.0 - 3);
    var second = random(1, max / 1.5 - 2 - first);
    var third = random(1, max / 1.2 - 1 - first - second);
    var fourth = max - first - second - third;
    if ((first < max / 10 || second < max / 10 || third < max / 10 || fourth < max / 10) || (first > max / 1.2 || second > max / 1.2 || third > max / 1.2 || fourth > max / 1.2) {
        reken(max);
    }
    else {
        status.innerHTML = first + " - " + second + " - " + third + " - " + fourth + " / " + (first + second + third + fourth );
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx that `else` statement did it

Comment: @ThomasPereira No problem, glad I could help. If my answer gave you enough information, please feel free to upvote it or mark it as "answer". Good luck!